# Using transform to send additional parameters. But only one time?

Tags: inertiajs

I use InertiaJS for my Vue/Laravel application and have an issue currently when submitting my MultiStepForm. I have these two methods:

```
const validateStep = (stepIndex) => {

    form
        .transform((formData) => ({
            ...formData,
            step: activeStepIndex.value,
        }))
        .post(route('professional.setup.validate'), {
            preserveState: true,
            preserveScroll: true,
            onSuccess: () => !form.hasErrors ? activateNextStep(stepIndex) : null,
        });
};

const submitForm = () => {
    form.post(route('professional.setup.finish'), {
        preserveState: true,
        preserveScroll: true,
    });
};
```

In order to validate the steps, I pass the relevant step as an additional parameter to the endpoint `professional.setup.finish`.

Now, when validation is finished and I am in the last step, I call the `submitForm` method. Strangley, in this request, made to `professional.setup.finish` there is still the `step` being sent as a payload to the backend.

Why is the step still included here and how can I get rid of it?